# Почему файлы не вызывают друг друга бесконечно при использовании import

Tags: python, импорт

Всем привет.
Вопрос возник потому, что хочу подробнее разобрать работу импорта.
Такая ситуация:

- я создаю два файла и импортирует первый во второй и второй в первый.
- в первом и во втором файле вывожу строку в терминал.
- почему я получаю только 3 строки вывода в терминале и не происходит бесконечного цикла?

Comment: Так-то питон проверяет был ли импортирован модуль. Вообще, модули доступны в переменной: `import sys;print(sys.modules)`

Comment: Спасибо, понял)